# Can't find where Xcode flag is set

Tags: xcode, build, parsekit

I'm trying to archive ParseKit in the latest Xcode release (4.6?) and keep stopping in a flag that is not being used:

```
clang: error: argument unused during compilation: '-flto'
```

I've double checked the project and no unusual flags seem to be set. I've googled for what that might mean but can't find anything. `clang -cc1 --help` doesn't seem to be very helpful although I admit I may be missing something in there.

Has anyone managed to archive ParseKit with the latest Xcode? How can I remove that flag from the build process?

---

To make it clear: I have no problems adding ParseKit as a dependent project or creating a debug build. What I can't do is archive, a release build.

Comment: The flag means 'link time optimization' so look in the linker-flags section of the Xcode project (in the Release bit only by the sound of it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed Link Time Optimization to "No" for Debug and Release builds and things build just fine.

Comment: You added a comment, not a response. I +1 your comment, though.